# Function call to AndroidJabaObject to an instance of com.prime31.PlayGameServicesPlugin causes the application to stop responding

Tags: android, google-play-services

Using Prime31 PlayGameServices attempting to call 'authenticate' causes the game to stop responding very soon after.

There isn't much I can show as there's literally no logs showing up in logcat.

Is there any way I can debug this?

I did notice 'enableDebugPrints' on the AndroidJavaObject was 'false' and I don't know how to set it to true, which might help with prints?

I've tried catching an exception but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot, I was running logcat -s Unity under the mistaken belief all related traces to the crash should be found there - makes sense it wasn't as the Google Play Services loads up its own little window, doesn't make sense why when Google Play fails it takes the host app down with it.

Just a plain logcat revealed the issue was caused by an improper configuration of Google Play Game Services, for some reason that means the application will stop responding, instead of simply failing a sign in attempt with a helpful error which would be much more reasonable.